How to let the Explode modifier only affect the mesh via Weight Paints?

There is an effect that I found that involves the scene breaking away (think of Coraline once the Other World falls apart when she wins the 'game'). I'd like to replicate that effect in Blender by using the Dynamic Paint, and the Explode modifier. I got the Dynamic Paint portion done, the only part I'm stuck at is trying to get the Explode modifier to only affect the Weight Paint.

The modifier order is [ Dynamic Paint -> Particle System -> Explode ]. "dp_weight" is the name of the Vertex Group that serves as the exploding particle system.
Is there a way where the Explode modifier can only affect the weight-painted polys while using an animated Dynamic Paint for the weight-paint?
EDIT: I've found in the Vertex Group in the Explode modifier. Without the Dynamic Paint, the intended effect is there. But I'm still not sure regarding the animated Dynamic Brush.

why do you want to use weight paint for that? Why can't you just change the vertex group (which is nowadays very easy via geometry nodes)?
